# Scraping values using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to scrape "Short interest" and "% of float shorted" values from https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl. I have tried using xpath, but it returns an Error.

````
import requests
from lxml import html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl"
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

per_of_float_shorted = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[14]/span[1]')[0].text()
short_interest = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[14]/span[1]')[0].text()

print(short_interest)
print(per_of_float_shorted)```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 11, in <module>
    per_of_float_shorted = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[14]/span[1]')[0].text()
IndexError: list index out of range

Thank you.
````

Comment: Have you tried using beautifulsoup to parse the html rather than lxml?

Comment: @scotty3785 no, actually. I am new to web scraping, and find navigating children tags difficult. This method worked for me earlier, and I thought it would work this time too. Could you help me with BeautifulSoup please

Comment: Use soup.find or soup.findAll to find your element by tag, class or id.

Comment: The website realized that you were using a bot to scrape the site. You will have to either look at workarounds (so that the site does not realized that a bot is being used) or use selenium (which may also fail).

Comment: Can you mention some workaround strategies, because Selenium too is unable to read the html @agastya

Comment: I'll look into it and get back to you

Comment: https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/AAOI - I can even use this site to get the percent of float value. Would this help?

Comment: Have you tries scraping it yet?

Comment: @agastya I used the wsj.com url to get the values, could not get a way to scrape the url in my original code

Comment: It's extremely difficult to get around robot checks. I suggest that you use wsj ( or perhaps another website or api) to get your data, because trying to get past the check will most likely be a waste of effort. I'm really sorry that I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: Sure no worries. Thank you